# How to trigger a function when user taps on google map markers - Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers, google-maps-flutter, fluttermap

How can we execute a function for example `_markerPressed()` in google map when user taps on a **marker**?

I dont want to show a popup I know its possible using `infoWindow`.
I want to, for example open a card on screen.

[image]

I've tried the `onTap:` and `onLongPress:` functions but it's only working while tapping on the **map** not the markers.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 final Marker marker = Marker(
          markerId: markerId,
          position: LatLng(
            center.latitude + sin(_markerIdCounter * pi / 6.0) / 20.0,
            center.longitude + cos(_markerIdCounter * pi / 6.0) / 20.0,
          ),
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: markerIdVal, snippet: '*'),

          onTap: (){
             //TODO: show your card
           },

          onDragEnd: (LatLng position) => _onMarkerDragEnd(markerId, position),
          onDrag: (LatLng position) => _onMarkerDrag(markerId, position),
        );
```

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master_archive/packages/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter/example/lib/place_marker.dart